# how to create direct link to cms articles

Tags: php, mysql, seo, content-management-system

I'm creating a simple CMS with a table called 'articles' that all the articles are stored in it.

In my AddArticle.php page on the website I have a form that creates the articles and feeds the table.

Now I'm confused with article linking.

As far as I know a CMS doesn't generate a page per new article (say article1.php, article2.php and etc).

But you can see that links like www.mysite.com/how-to-create-direct-link-to-a-cms-article works on them (There is not a file wih that name but the link works).

So how can I have direct links to CMS articles, then? And how can I make them SEO-Friendly?

Comment: That is the title slug in url which is used I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a slug to use in your URL. Either you allow the user to enter his slug or you create the slug automatically from the article's title. One thing to keep in mind is that you'll need to make sure the slug is unique.

Imagine the title is something like "How to create direct link to cms articles", you could automatically create the slug "how-to-create-direct-link-to-cms-article" (much like StackOverflow does).

Then, you need to code your CMS to understand that, whenever you get a URL with the pattern `www.mysite.com/how-to-create-direct-link-to-cms-articles`, it should look for an article.

The most simple solution is to create some kind of route like `www.mysite.com/articles/{{slug}}`, where `{{slug}}` is the slug saved on DB. Here I've used `articles` to distinguish the articles from any other page (like contacts).

If you're using some kind of PHP framework for your CMS, this would be rather simple, since you can define routes in most frameworks. If you're not (I hope you are), you need to create all that logic.

A final thing to notice: You'll need mod_rewrite to make your urls friendly. Without url rewrite your URL will look something like `www.mysite.com/articles.php?slug=how-to-create-direct-link-to-cms-articles`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Actually I'm not using a framework and URL routing is a very new subject to me. Do you think I can use something like http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7405-PHP-Parse-and-build-URIs-from-routing-rules.html or http://www.sitepoint.com/web-routing-in-php-with-aura-router ?

Comment: @user3114355 Yes, from what I've read you can use either one of those solutions. You just need to integrate the class or package in your project. Please take a moment to [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/266555) if you think this answered your question. Thanks!